# FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject

Tags: java, android, eclipse, time, android-asynctask

I want to call a web service but I have an exception

logcat

```
09-15 09:00:08.600: E/AndroidRuntime(1398): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-15 09:00:08.600: E/AndroidRuntime(1398): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject
09-15 09:00:08.600: E/AndroidRuntime(1398):     at net.simonvt.menudrawer.samples.WebserviceCall.getFahrenheit(WebserviceCall.java:38)
09-15 09:00:08.600: E/AndroidRuntime(1398):     at net.simonvt.menudrawer.samples.DotNetWebService$1.onClick(DotNetWebService.java:46)
09-15 09:00:08.600: E/AndroidRuntime(1398):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
09-15 09:00:08.600: E/AndroidRuntime(1398):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
09-15 09:00:08.600: E/AndroidRuntime(1398):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
09-15 09:00:08.600: E/AndroidRuntime(1398):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-15 09:00:08.600: E/AndroidRuntime(1398):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-15 09:00:08.600: E/AndroidRuntime(1398):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
09-15 09:00:08.600: E/AndroidRuntime(1398):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-15 09:00:08.600: E/AndroidRuntime(1398):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-15 09:00:08.600: E/AndroidRuntime(1398):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
09-15 09:00:08.600: E/AndroidRuntime(1398):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
09-15 09:00:08.600: E/AndroidRuntime(1398):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

mainactivity.java

```
public class DotNetWebService extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dot_net_web_service);

    final Button webserviceCallButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.webservice);
    final EditText webserviceResponse = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.webserviceResponse);

    WebserviceCall com = new WebserviceCall(); 


    //Call Webservice class method and pass values and get response
    String aResponse = com.getFahrenheit("Place");  
}}
```

WebserviceCall.java

```
public class WebserviceCall {

/**
 * Variable Decleration................
 * 
 */
String namespace = "http://tempuri.org";
private String url = "my webservice";

String SOAP_ACTION="http://tempuri.org/Place";  
WebserviceCall() {
}


/**
 * Set Envelope
 */
public String getFahrenheit(String method) {
    String fahren = "erorr";
 SoapObject request = new SoapObject(namespace, method);
    //Set Name
    //Create envelope
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    //Set output SOAP object
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    //Create HTTP call object
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(url);

    try {
        //Invole web service
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        //Get the response
        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
        //Assign it to fahren static variable
       fahren = response.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        fahren=e.toString();
    }
    return fahren;
}
/************************************/
}
```

Comment: The stacktrace is only telling you that the org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject dependency is not available

Comment: but i added 
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;

Comment: Where did you add it? It seems it is not available at runtime. Did you use Maver to build your code?

Comment: this is my import    import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.AndroidHttpTransport;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

Comment: Please edit your question to add this code. So it seems you have this dependency at compile time but not at runtime. How do you package your artifact?

Comment: no this is my logcot and my exception is runtime

Comment: Dear, can you tell me how solve it? I was update my Android Studio to 2.0 and Ksoap2 crashed... and show NoClassDefFound PropertyInfo! Incredible!!!